# objective-c create and stroke an arc with CG

Tags: core-graphics

I was following a Ray Wenderlich tutorial on creating arcs:

http://www.raywenderlich.com/33193/core-graphics-tutorial-arcs-and-paths

-what I am looking to do is begin at point a (a fixed point) and locate where the user touches the screen, if it is + point A, then I want to draw an arc to that point. Though I don't return any errors I also don't get the path to be stroked. Could someone review the code below and see what I am doing wrong?

```
    @implementation KIP_Arc

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        // Initialization code
    }
    return self;
}

- (void) setArc {

    //set the frame
    float frameX = _startPoint.x;
    float frameY = _startPoint.y;
    float frameW = _endPoint.x;
    float frameH = 50.0;

    [self setFrame:CGRectMake(frameX, frameY, frameW, frameH)];
    self.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

}

- (BOOL)isFlipped {
    return YES;
}


- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect  {

    [[UIColor blackColor] set];

    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    CGContextSaveGState(context);
    CGRect arcRect = self.frame;
    CGMutablePathRef arcPath = [self createArcPathFromBottomOfRect:arcRect:25.0];
    CGContextAddPath(context, arcPath);
    CGContextClip(context);
    CGContextFillPath(context);
    CGContextRestoreGState(context);

    CFRelease(arcPath);

}

- (CGMutablePathRef) createArcPathFromBottomOfRect : (CGRect) rect : (CGFloat) arcHeight {

    CGRect arcRect = CGRectMake(rect.origin.x, rect.origin.y + rect.size.height - arcHeight, rect.size.width, arcHeight);

    CGFloat arcRadius = (arcRect.size.height/2) + (pow(arcRect.size.width, 2) / (8*arcRect.size.height));
    CGPoint arcCenter = CGPointMake(arcRect.origin.x + arcRect.size.width/2, arcRect.origin.y + arcRadius);

    CGFloat angle = acos(arcRect.size.width / (2*arcRadius));
    CGFloat startAngle = radians(180) + angle;
    CGFloat endAngle = radians(360) - angle;


    CGMutablePathRef path = CGPathCreateMutable();
    CGPathAddArc(path, NULL, arcCenter.x, arcCenter.y, arcRadius, startAngle, endAngle, 0);
    CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, NULL, CGRectGetMaxX(rect), CGRectGetMinY(rect));
    CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, NULL, CGRectGetMinX(rect), CGRectGetMinY(rect));
    CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, NULL, CGRectGetMinX(rect), CGRectGetMaxY(rect));

    return path;
}

static inline double radians (double degrees){
    return degrees * M_PI/180;
}
```

Comment: Do you want to stroke or fill? The code you showed only tries to fill the path, not stroke it. Even removing the `CGContextClip` call is not going to make a stroke happen. (And speaking of things you can remove: You don't need to `gsave` and `grestore` if you're not going to do anything after restoring.)

Comment: You might also want to `[self setNeedsDisplay]` in `setArc`, unless you have set the view's `contentMode` to `UIViewContentModeRedraw`.

Answer (score 1):

[`CGContextClip`, as a side effect, empties the current path.](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CGContext/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/CGContextClip) When you call `CGContextFillPath` immediately afterward, the current path is empty, so you fill nothing.

As its name implies, `CGContextFillPath` restricts itself to the context's current path. (If it didn't, its name would just be `CGContextFill`.) So, you don't need to clip.

Drop the `CGContextClip` call and just use `CGContextFillPath`.